# Is this sensible index placement for a Christoffel symbol of the second kind?

Tags: general-relativity, notation

I am trying to wrap my head around index notation and I have found a question in a textbook I am unsure of the answer of. It gives the expression:
$$
t_{jk} = Γ^{i}_{jk}  u_{i}
$$
and asks for an explanation as to whether this has sensible index placement?

I have only seen the Christoffel symbol of the second kind as part of the covariant derivative. The amount of free and dummy indices in this expression makes sense but I am wondering if the Christoffel symbol should be multiplied by a vector rather than a covector? If someone could explain this to me I'd be grateful!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could just as correctly have $\Gamma^i_{jk}v^j$, that's valid in index notation. What makes you think the Christoffel symbols *must* be contracted with a vector?

Comment: I completely wasn't sure, I guess I was wondering whether it needed to have an upstairs index (be a vector) to match the upstairs 'i' on the Christoffel symbol. I can now see that since it is a dummy index, and represents a summation, its placement doesn't matter as long as it is repeated somewhere on the same side?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean, but if you're asking if $\Gamma^i_{jk}u^i$ would be correct? The answer is no, that would be invalid in index notation since you have a repeated up index, the only valid way to have repeated indices in tensor index notation is one up one down.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was asking originally- sorry for the confusion- I probably could have worded it better! Thank you for that explanation, that's exactly what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sensible index placement has a contraction between an upper and a lower index. In this case, an upper $i$ is contracted with a lower $i$, so the expression makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

If by a vector you mean contravariant vector $u^i$ then this wouldn't be correct since you can not contract it with the Christoffel symbol $\Gamma^{i}_{jk}$ and obtain $t_{jk}$. You can perform the contraction between upper and lower indices.